# Array to string conversion on symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make a call to my symfony method which call an API method via AJAX. The parameters are an id (int), text(string) and an associative array. When i make the call symfony give me an array to string error.

Here's a snap of the code :

```
var final_tab = {};
    
    var tab = {'A': 'VALUE', 'B': 'VALUE', 'C': 'VALUE'};

    $.each(tab,function(key, value){

        final_tab[key] = {
            'o1': $('#H'+key+'_O_1M').val(),
            'f1': $('#H'+key+'_F_1M').val(),
            'o2': $('#H'+key+'_F_2M').val(),
            'f2': $('#H'+key+'_F_2M').val()
        }
    });

   $.ajax({
            url : "call_it",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'id' : 41372972,
                'text' : 'open',
                'final' : final_tab

            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('OK');
            },
            error: function(data, status) {
                console.log('KO');
            }
        });
```

Here's the parameters passed into the method (the names of the parameters are different, I've tried to adapt an  example for the stackoverflow users) :

[image]

Here's the controller methode in symfony :

```
        $mail = "test";
        $pass = "test";

        $oauth = new OAuth($mail, $pass);

        $baseUrl = $this->container->getParameter('url_api');

        $link = "{$baseUrl}test/" . $mail . "/" . $pass . "/test";

        $oauth->fetch($link, $_REQUEST, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
        $response = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse(), true);

        return $response
```

Finally, here's the symfony error :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Typo here: `return $resposne`. Is `$oauth->getLastResponse()` a string or an array?

Comment: Symfony show me an error in this stape :  `$oauth->fetch($link, $_REQUEST, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);`

Comment: Symfony error page also shows you a full stack trace of the exception, which gives you all you need to locate the problem. You haven't pasted it here.

Comment: What are you trying to return back to the user?  Right now your response will be an array or object which doesn't really work...